# Сохранить карту Google с помощью GMap.Net для OffLine работы

Tags: c#, google-maps, gmap.net

Необходимо сохранить карту Google с помощью GMap.Net в базе данных для дальнейшего использования в offline режиме с разными zoom-мами.

---

Подключил карту `gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap;`  С параметром `GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerAndCache;` Карту показывает, недостающие тайлы подкачивает. На диске обнаружил файл `Data.gmdb` размером 30МВ.
Отключил интернет. Загрузил карту - карта отображается. Однако если меняю масштаб отсутствующие тайлы не подгружает. Подключил интернет. Вижу тайлы подгружает.
В какой-то момент обнаружил что файл `Data.gmdb` увеличился до 60МВ.
Отключив интернет обнаружил что для некоторых масштабов тайлы подгрузились. Пришел к выводу сохранить в базу карту можно. Или я в чем-то ошибаюсь?

Сегодня попробовал код из примера на github:

```
RectLatLng area = new RectLatLng(LatInit, LongInit, 0.0000005, 0.0000005);//gMapControl1.SelectedArea;
if (!area.IsEmpty)
{
    for (int i = (int)gMapControl1.Zoom; i <= gMapControl1.MaxZoom; i++)
    {
        using (TilePrefetcher obj = new TilePrefetcher())
        {
            obj.Shuffle = gMapControl1.Manager.Mode != AccessMode.CacheOnly;
            obj.Start(area, i, gMapControl1.MapProvider, gMapControl1.Manager.Mode == AccessMode.CacheOnly ? 0 : 100,
                gMapControl1.Manager.Mode == AccessMode.CacheOnly ? 0 : 1);
            obj.Owner = this;
            obj.ShowCompleteMessage = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Процесс поиска тайлов идет, записи тайлов в базу нет. Пробовал как для googlemap так и OpenStreet и для других - результат тот же - не сохраняет в базу.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, могу посоветовать найти метод сохранения карты в сэмпле (или демо) самого GMap.NET. Я точно помню, что там была фнукция сохранения карты в разных масштабах

Answer (score 0):

Сомневаюсь, что вообще это возможно. Политика Google запрещает использовать их карты offline. В своё время мы использовали OpenMap для этого.